# Angular5 merging an array by index

Tags: arrays, ionic3, angular5

I need to merge an array inside an another array by their positions:

**Array1**

```
(5) ["Cliente solicita reenvío de pedido", "Equipamiento Perdido", "Pedido cancelado a petición de cliente", "Pedido con documentación pendiente", "Pedido en incidencia"]
0: "Cliente solicita reenvío de pedido"
1: "Equipamiento Perdido"
2: "Pedido cancelado a petición de cliente"
3: "Pedido con documentación pendiente"
4: "Pedido en incidencia"
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**Array2**

```
(5) ["EQSOLREENVIO", "EQPER", "EQCAN", "EQRECHKODOC", "EQAUS,EQCDE,EQDDE,EQINACCE,EQVAC"]
0: "EQSOLREENVIO"
1: "EQPER"
2: "EQCAN"
3: "EQRECHKODOC"
4: "EQAUS,EQCDE,EQINACCE,EQVAC"
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**Needed Output Example**

```
(5) ["Cliente solicita reenvío de pedido", "Equipamiento Perdido", "Pedido cancelado a petición de cliente", "Pedido con documentación pendiente", "Pedido en incidencia"]
    0: "Cliente solicita reenvío de pedido"
       Array(1): 
       0: EQSOLREENVIO
    1: "Equipamiento Perdido"
       Array(1): 
       0: EQPER
    2: "Pedido cancelado a petición de cliente"
       Array(1): 
       0: EQCAN
    3: "Pedido con documentación pendiente"
       Array(4): 
       0: EQAUS
       1: EQCDE
       2: EQINACCE
       3: EQVAC
    4: "Pedido en incidencia"
       Array(1): 
       0: EQPER
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

The values in Array2 need to be added inside Array1 by their positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the forEach function to create an array just like you want and use the second parameter for the current index.

```
const array1 = ["foo", "foo2"]
const array2 = ["bar", "bar2"]

let mergedArray = []
array1.forEach( (entry, index) => {
  mergedArray[entry] = array2[index]
})

console.log(mergedArray)
```

Better to do some checks on your arrays beforehand to make sure they have the same number of elements.

Comment: entry[0] is giving me an error that its only allowed to be read :/

Comment: sorry, I answered a bit too quickly. Simpler to use forEach for this one IMO

Comment: How could I make each entry an array so I can access each one separately?

Comment: Your awnser makes only one array with all values from array 2 in each value in array1 but like I mentioned in my question I need each value from array2 seperated

Comment: You mean when your entry has commas, split them and add each word as an array element? Then you should use the split method that turns a string into an array given a specific separator: var entries = str.split(',');